# Scratch 2.0 is no longer considered a "free" language. Does this retroactively make cops-and-robbers cop answers in Scratch 2.0 non-competitive?

Tags: discussion, policy, answers, cops-and-robbers

As per [this question's answers](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7822/what-constitutes-a-free-language-for-cops-and-robbers), Scratch 2.0 is no longer considered a "free" language. As per [this question's accepted answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11726/allowing-non-free-languages-in-cops-and-robbers-challenges-when-marked-as-non-co), non-free languages are allowed if marked as non-competing.

Scratch 2.0 used to be runnable on the Web through any browser with Adobe Flash. However, now that Scratch 3.0 has superseded Scratch 2.0, Scratch 2.0 is only runnable through the [offline editor](https://scratch.mit.edu/download/scratch2), which is only available for Windows and Mac OS, both of which are non-free operating systems.

Should cops-and-robbers cop answers in Scratch 2.0 retroactively be marked non-competitive?

Comment: Are you sure the offline editor cannot run under ReactOS or Wine?

Comment: Don't sulphurous/phosphorous work... plus WINE is a thing

Comment: The [full source](https://github.com/LLK/scratch-flash) of Scratch 2.0 is still available, and it looks like you can build it yourself, and still run it through the browser.

Comment: Things such as https://ruffle.rs (a browser Flash Emulator) exist and are free and open-source (tho Ruffle doesn't support all of flash so idk about Scratch 2)